# Add border/shading to picture when cell has same name as picture - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have built a heat map of the UK. Is it possible to have a certain county highlighted when a cell has the same name as the county?

The Heat Map is made of individual Pictures per County, which have been overlapped.  Ideally this would take effect as soon as you finished putting data into the cell.

I understand that Conditional Formatting is unlikely to work, and this will probably require VBA - also, when I try to apply an outline it is currently around the Picture rectangle instead of just the non-transparent part of the image.

Please ask me any questions if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to provide a **lot** more information about what you've done so far - for example, do you have individual shapes for each county?  Or one flat image of the UK?  Or carefully sized-and-grouped Named Ranges of cells?  Do you want this to happen when you type the text in (e.g. via the `Worksheet_Change` event) or when you click a button?

Comment: Cool idea but yes...much more information is needed. Also please include anything you've personally tried so far

Comment: Apologies. I've separated out the counties and they're all different pictures added together. Preferably a worksheet_change event would be perfect. Conditional formatting obviously won't work, but i'm not sure of what other method there is. The trouble i'm finding is that, as the counties are separate pictures rather than shapes, the border only puts a square border around the picture, rather than the borders of the county. The shadow effect seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Line, use Glow or Shadow, with a low-or-zero Transparency.  For example the following 2 subs will make a Shape called "Picture 1" on `Sheet1` start or stop glowing with 0 transparency, which will hopefully give a suitable outline.

```
Sub MakeShapeGlow()
    With Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Glow
        .Color.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
        .Color.TintAndShade = 0
        .Color.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Radius = 6
    End With
End Sub

Sub StopShapeGlow()
    Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Glow.Radius = 0
End Sub
```

**However** - you probably also want to bring the Shape to the Front, so that the other Pictures don't cover up the outline.  (You should be able to use "Record Macro" to get code for this)

You can trigger the change with something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "Cornwall" Then
        MakeShapeGlow
    Else
        StopShapeGlow
    End If
End Sub
```

(Obviously, a `For Each` loop that un-glows all shapes and then glows as shape based on name, such as "Pic_Cornwall" would be far more efficient than typing out new Subs and `If` chains for every county)